# Python: Remove everything except letters and whitespaces from string

Tags: python, regex

I have this code but stuck with regex:

```
text = "Itsa lovely day!!! Shabba"
regex = ur''# put it there
result = re.sub(regex, u'', text, flags=re.UNICODE)
assert result != "Itsa lovely day Shabba"
```

I tried something like this:

```
ur'[\W^[\s]]+'
```

and variants of it.

Can somebody provide a correct regex?

Comment: What is the last square in the `text` variable?

Comment: Something like `\ud83c\udfb6`

Comment: Just try [^\w\s]+ which will also retain digits and underscores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
import re

text = "Itsa lovely day!!! Shabba"
result = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', u'', text, flags=re.UNICODE)
print result
```

If you also want to allow numbers, just do this:

```
result = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\d\s]', u'', text, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Thanks. It Looks nice, but what about other whitespace symbols?

Comment: @kharandziuk, Perhaps you can add `\t\n` to the character class in the regex above which I just updated.

Comment: @sshashank124 Doesn't \s include \t and \n?  I thought that, in Python, it would include any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return,vertical tab, form feed, and next line.

Comment: @kharandziuk  Which "other" whitespace symbols concern you?

Comment: What about ß, Ä, Ö, Ü, ą, ź, ę, etc?

Comment: you can use @kjaquier's answer and just add additional conditions in the if clause

Answer (score 4):

You can also do that simply without regex :

```
text = "Itsa lovely day!!! Shabba"
result = "".join(x for x in text if x.isalpha() or x.isspace())
```